# Proble m in accessing internet on my PC using NetGear wireless card

Tags: windows-7, browsing, wireless-card

Recently I added a NetGear wifi card to my PC (Win 7) in order to browse to Internet. All the drivers were installed properly.

> **But the problem is i can't access sites other than google.com. For
>   rest of the sites, the site title is displayed on the browser, but the
>   site is not loaded.**

I checked the internet connection and its working properly. Also, i have tried different browsers too. But nothing seems to work.
I am able to browse when using my laptop.

What is the problem?

Comment: It sounds like google.com is in your cache.  If you can actually perform a google search, then you are connected to the internet, and there should be no reason you cannot connect to other websites.

Comment: @Ramhound: yes, i am able to use google search..but on clicking any link..the page doesn't load.